# Why matrix with full column rank has a left inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose $P$ is a matrix with a full column rank. Why there is a matrix $C$ such that $CP=I$?

Let's say the rank of $P$ is $r$.  I understand that since the column space $C(P)$ equals the column space $C(I_r)$. Then each column of $P$ can be transferred to each column of $I_r$, i.e. $$[p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_r](\alpha_{11},\alpha_{21},\cdots,\alpha_{r1})^{T}=(1,0,\cdots,0)^T,$$where $p_i$ means the $i^{\rm th}$ column of $P$. As a result, there should be a matrix $A$ such that $PA=I_r$, which is actually a right inverse. I don't understand why $P$ has a left inverse.

Comment: Is $P$ a square matrix?

Comment: Not necessarily. Let me write down the whole sentence. $A$  be a $m\times n$ matrix with rank $r$. Then $(P, Q)$ is said to be a rank factorization of $A$ if $A = PQ$, where $P$ has full column rank and $Q$ has a full row rank. Since $P$ has a full column rank and $Q$ has a full row rank, there are matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $CP=I$ and $QD=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming, for the sake of simplicity, the scalars to be real numbers.

Let $P$ be a $m \times n$ matrix with full column rank, so $n$ is the rank of $P$.

In the canonical bases, $P$ represents an morphism $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Since $P$ has full column rank, $u$ is injective, that is, $(u(e_1),u(e_2),\ldots,u(e_n))$ is free, so there are vectors $s_1,\ldots,s_{m-n} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ completing that real family into a basis.

We can define a morphism $v:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by specifyig its values on the aforementioned basis: let us require $v(s_k)=0$ and $v(u(e_l))=e_l$.

Then the matrix $C$ representing $v$ in the canonical bases is a left inverse for $P$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Also, I noted that $(P^TP)^{-1}P^T$ is a left inverse of $P$.

Comment: That only works for real numbers, where $A$ and $A^TA$ always have the same kernel dimension (thus the same rank). In particular, if $A$ is a real matrix with full column rank, then $A^TA$ is a square matrix with full rank so is invertible. Then $((A^TA)^{-1}A^T)A=(A^TA)^{-1}(A^TA)=I$.